# Google Search Data API

Tags: ios, api, swift, google-search

In google, some searches might bring up some data found by google (For instance, searching "bitcoin price" brings up data on pricing in a little box at the top, as does searching "2 plus 2". Is there a Google API that will fetch just the data pulled up in the box (as in, If this API was given the keyword "Bitcoin", it would return the price but not the links to websites below). Is there such a "data box" API that will work with the Swift Programming Language (It is for an iOS app)?

I couldn't find any previous questions like this, but there may be some, as I don't know the proper terminology (If anyone happens to know the official name of what I called "data boxes", do tell! Also, I apologize for use of the API tag, I just don't know the name of the API I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official name is "OneBox".

The underlying APIs are unavailable and brokered by Google and private data providers. Your best bet is to find the data sources directly and use their API; which will probably involve an exchange of money or other formal agreement.